# Linq to add missing items from one list of strings to another list

Tags: string, list, linq, csv, reporting-services

I have a method that finds data missing with a known pattern in an actual CSV file produced by SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and then adds that missing data to an expected file for later comparison.
I know this isn't ideal but the data with the pattern has been archive from my source database that I use to build up an expected CSV file for comparison against my Reporting database whos data has not been archived. Only data with this pattern will be missing/archived in my expected file.

The method below is working and creates a new merged expected file with all the missing data from the actual file in the correct position and all the original data also is present and moved to new positions to fit the missing data.

Anyway, I'm trying to practice Linq techniques and am wondering how I could replace the "for" loop in my logic. I did attempt a where following with a select but can't seem to quite get the logic/syntax right.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
public static byte[] GetExpectedReportDataWithMissingActualData(
        byte[] expectedReportData)
    {
        if (expectedReportData == null) { return expectedReportData; }

        var _expectedReportDataLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\temp\ExpectedReport.csv");
        var _actualReportDataLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\temp\ActualReport.csv");

        // Identify the lines from the actual that contain "missing_pattern"
        var _actualReportDataMissingRows = _actualReportDataLines.Where(reportLine => reportLine.Contains("missing_pattern"));

        // There is no missing pattern data in the actual, simply return the expected as is
        if (_actualReportDataMissingRows.Count() == 0) { return expectedReportData; }

        var _expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows = new List<string>();
        var _missingRowsAdded = 0;
        for (var _counter = 0; _counter < _actualReportDataLines.Length; _counter++)
        {
            // Check does the current row in the actual contain the string "missing_pattern"
            if (_actualReportDataMissingRows.Contains(_actualReportDataLines[_counter]))
            {
                // Ensure that these records are not in the expected already
                if (_expectedReportDataLines[_counter - _missingRowsAdded] != _actualReportDataLines[_counter])
                {
                    _expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows.Insert(_counter, _actualReportDataLines[_counter]);
                    _missingRowsAdded++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            _expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows.Add(_expectedReportDataLines[_counter - _missingRowsAdded]);
        }

        return _expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows.Select(
            reportLine => reportLine + Environment.NewLine).SelectMany(reportLine => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reportLine)).ToArray();
    }
```

I've added example files here as requested to hopefully clarify the scenario.

ExpectedReport.csv

```
Line1Item1,Line1Item2,Line1Item3
Line2Item1,Line2Item2,Line2Item3
```

ActualReport.csv

```
Line1Item1,Line1Item2,Line1Item3
Line2Item1,missing_pattern,Line2Item3
Line3Item1,Line3Item2,Line3Item3
```

Returned strings before conversion to byte array

```
Line1Item1,Line1Item2,Line1Item3
Line2Item1,missing_pattern,Line2Item3
Line3Item1,Line3Item2,Line3Item3
```

Line1 is taken from the ExpectedReport.csv  
Line2 is taken from the ActualReport.csv  
Line3 is taken from the ExpectedReport.csv

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output? When I try to run test data through your function, it doesn't do what I expect from your description.

Comment: It's hard to provide input & output data as the data type is byte array. I've the byte array conversion working & it's the linq syntax in the for loop that I'm trying to solve. The byte array stuff could be stripped out if it makes understanding easier. I've added the contents of example files to my question to help you understand the concept.

Comment: Your code seems to do a lot more than your example implies "ensure that these records are not in the expected already" - what is that for?

Comment: If you take line one in ActualReport.csv `Line1Item1,Line1Item2,Line1Item3`, when building the new merged version of the file in variable `_expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows` we want to use the line from ExpectedReport.csv by doing `_expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows.Add(_expectedReportDataLines[_counter - _missingRowsAdded]);` instead of taking it from ActualReport.csv by doing `_expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows.Insert(_counter, _actualReportDataLines[_counter]);`

Comment: I still don't see how that is related to what the code is doing or the comment - how could they be in expected already?

Comment: I start with 2 files/List<string>, the ExpectedReport.csv file has 2 lines in it, while I am looping the ActualReport.csv, if the same line exist in the same position in both files (like line one), then I want to take the line from the expected file & add it to my newly created merged list version `_expectedReportDataWithMergedMissingRows`, otherwise the line does not exist in ExpectedReport.csv at this position so I want to Insert the actual line at this position in my newly created merged list. The question I am asking is do you have suggestions to **convert this for loop to linq**?

Comment: If it is the same line, why does it matter which file it comes from? If they aren't the same, how do you know when to use the line from expected vs actual? My problem is, your code shown doesn't seem to match what you are saying.

Comment: If it is the same line, it doesn't matter, I just choose my expected file, which is my file used to compare expected against actual as the source as there's no point comparing the actual file to the actual file! When they aren't the same I simply want to merge the missing line into my new expected merged list of expected & missing actual. I feel like these comment are getting way off topic. Again, the question that I asked is **"how I could replace the "for" loop in my logic."** I am happy that my current for loop is doing what I want it to do but am interested in getting it working with linq.